# Error while restarting Redis on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: redis

I am quite new at Redis. I tried to configure it on my Ubuntu 18.04. After installing I changed `supervised no` to `supervised systemd` and tried tor restart Redis server with `sudo nano /etc/redis/redis.conf`  but I got the following:

`Job for redis-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.`

`See "systemctl status redis-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you do this recommendation: `"systemctl status redis-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details` ?

Comment: I did. I didn't know what I have to do. I got the following:

```rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ Messaging Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-10-25 11:04:07 CEST; 1h 37min ago
  Process: 357 ExecStartPost=/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server-wait (code=exited, status=70)
  Process: 356 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 356 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)```